# How to communicate with Qt widget through external command?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm working on a tool, on the main window of the tool there are few Qt widgets added on it.
When we used to RMB click on the Qt widget, a context menu pops up (and via eventFilter few functions have been called) to do the required work- say, doTask() slot gets called up with the receiver object.

Now I have to add a banner menu on the window, which has to copy all the features of RMB context menu.
Since this banner menu is not of Qt, but written in some internal functions (say, LISP) I have problems in calling that slot function - doTask(), as I don't know what is the receiver object.

How can I communicate with a Qt widget through some external command/language?

Please add comment if anything is not clear in this.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not expose a simple C style method from a QT aware object that acts as a proxy for the slot calls. ie Your banner calls method, method then calls appropriate slots?

Comment: Hi Gaz, I'm very new to QT and dont know much about QT aware object and it might be a standard question of Qt.
If you could provide any link or any tutorial to read more about what you are suggesting, it would be really helpful.

Comment: A "Qt-aware object" is basically any object that's compiled with QT's moc tool and therefore can have `signals`. But it doesn't solve the problem; you know have to find out what _that_ object is.

Answer (score 1):

Your basic problem is just knowing the receiver object. Once you do, you can call its slot directly (doesn't need to go through a signal).

The menu knows this, because it keeps a pointer to the receiver object. Your own banner menu must do the same. "It doesn't know the receiver object" must therefore be fixed.

Comment: Could you please help me in these queries.. What would be the best way to fix this problem "It doesn't know the receiver object", should I use Qt's findChildren function to search for that particular receiver object or any other approach? And if I say, banner menu is supposed to work only when a cell of particular widget is selected, (like, if you select something in the widget then only you are supposed to use the banner menu). Will this information help in searching for receiver object? Actually what I'm working is to , Copy RMB context menus functionality in Banner Menus.

Comment: Look, Qt signals are basically just a messaging system. We can help you with the Qt part, but you are the only one who knows which object should receive the signal. We don't, and your program doesn't. For the RMB click, Qt can figure out that the receiver is the widget below the mouse pointer.

Comment: Thanks for the help MSlaters. It'd be great if you help a bit more with the Qt part.
As much I understand, I should make it to emit a signal from the banner menus callback, which would be connected with the corresponding slot in the particular Qt Widget and that way I can communicate with my C function to Qt Widget?

Sorry for asking so much questions in comments, better if you could provide me some links or tutorials where C functions emit a signal which can be handled by QtWidgets.

Comment: **There is no Qt part**. Sorry but I can't seem to help you. You fail to understand the problem that you have. Also, where did that C function suddenly come from? Signals are only emitted by Qt objects. (class defined with `Q_OBJECT` macro)

Comment: Sorry for mentioning C, actually the function used for creating banner menus in my tool has a wrapper which C so I was mentioning it explicitly and asking about how can I call Qwidget's function through this C function. 
Now I got your point, it was great learning few things here. Thanks.
I'd google more about it. Thanks for giving your time :)